# How to sort data from a JSON ARRAY (list of maps) and export them to excel/csv

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I have a JSON array (list of maps) similar to:

```
def listOfMap = [[TESTCASE:1, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'PASS'], 
      [TESTCASE:2, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'], 
      [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'], 
      [TESTCASE:4, METHOD:'TYPETEXT', RESULT:'FAIL']]
```

I want to generate a report **with unique method names in one column and their % failure in another column** and export to csv/excel/html. The report should be in the following pattern

[image: Report :]

1) What is the shortest groovy code possible to achieve this?
2) How can we export the data to excel/csv?

I have these code snippets available but unable to connect the dots

a) To get the list of unique methods
listOfMap.METHOD.unique()

b) To get the count of runs for each METHOD (here i want to loop through above output)
listOfMap.count { map -> map.METHOD == 'CLICK'}

c) To get the FAIL count of all methods from above list
listOfMap.count { map -> map.METHOD == 'CLICK' && map.RESULT == 'FAIL' }

Now i want to calculate: (Count of FAIL result for each METHOD / Total Runs of each METHOD * 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def percentage (map){
     (map.FAIL ?: 0) / ((map.PASS ?: 0) + (map.FAIL ?: 0)) * 100
}

def result = listOfMap.groupBy{it.METHOD}
                      .collectEntries{[(it.key) : percentage(it.value.countBy{it.RESULT})]}

def outputCsv = new File('/pathToReport/report.csv')
outputCsv.write "S.No;MethodName;Failture %\n"
result.eachWithIndex{ entry, index ->
   outputCsv << "${index+1};${entry.key};${entry.value}\n"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like charm!! Can you pls suggest code to export the same data (result) to **EXCEL** as shown in the image

Comment: xls is more complex format. You need to use additional tools like: http://jameskleeh.com/groovy-excel-builder/